# Mouse buttons don't work while typing

Tags: laptop, drivers, mouse, touchpad, typing

Hey guys I need some help if you can, when I am typing I can't use the mouse buttons to click on anything. It's particularly annoying  when I am in a game I can't click anything while moving around.

I have a Medion Erazer x7859 Laptop.

It states it has a synaptic smbus touchpad driver but I can't for the life of me get the synaptics control panel to show up. I have tried reinstalling the drivers, tried different drivers and resetting the BIOS etc so no luck there. And without is there seems to be no other settings to change this.

I have also went into the registry editor :

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > PrecisionTouchPad then changed "AAPThreshold" to 0`.

That didn't work either.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are saying you dont have any touchpad applet in control panel? as there should be one - and a settings disable touchpad while typing - at least the symptoms you have described reminded me seeing that at some point in the past on another laptop.

Comment: I can use my touchpad while typing thats fine, its just the mouse buttons dont work. My mouse has synaptic smbus driver and the 'correct' one is installed however on the mouse settings there is no synaptic control panel. Thanks for the reply!